# How the DC source can make reverse bias diode?

Tags: circuit-design

I was studying up on the material we are going through, and found this [video that talked about "biased clamper circuit."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLRuU3VcXPA)

At 1:34, it is confusing, how can the DC source make a reverse bias diode?

It seems to me like there should be any effect, because it's a DC source.

Comment: One end is connected to the DC source. Hint: What is the waveform seen at the other end?

Comment: You should make a screenshot of the  circuit from video, or draw the circuit using the site's built in circuit editor.